# How do I drop things?

Tags: stardew-valley

Sometimes my inventory gets full and I don't want some of the things because I have found better things I want instead. How can I drop or otherwise dispose of those things to get things I do want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can select an item and move it outside of the inventory area and then release the item.
2. You can select an item, move it to the trash can, and then simply delete it.  I know on the controller if you select an item with A, and then hit B, it auto teleports the cursor to the trash can.  The delete key will also immediately trash a selected item.

Note that the former might get impacted by your wearing a ring that has a larger item attraction distance.  It's conceivable you could re-pickup something.

Comment: +1 : Just to add, it is impossible, at the time of writing this, to drop the starting tools. I DO NOT in any way, advise in attempting this, however.

Comment: This does not seem to work? How do you move a item? Click on it?

Comment: Yes, you click on something.

Comment: I had my inventory and my bottom bar mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

Press E to access the inventory. Then drag a item into the trash can on the right. You can drop it outside of the inventory as well but you just immediately pick it up again most of the time.

[image: How to drop items in Stardew Valley]

Comment: I've successfully dropped things without picking them up while I had room to pick them up, so it's not impossible.

Comment: Yea, I am sure its possible. It is just what I tried at first and got frustrated as It always just immediately appeared in my inventory again.

Answer (score -2):

You can also drop fish (and other items from your inventory) back into the water where you caught them if your inventory is full. Instead of dragging the fish to the trash to throw it away, release it over the water besides the trash/around your inventory. Not sure if this has any effect on gameplay whether you throw it away in the trash or release it back in the ocean/river.